# Spring Thymeleaf Dependency Overwriting Eureka Template?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-cloud-netflix

I want to create a second page that displays information about the configuration profile that is active in the spring boot application using spring mvc. This information should be displayed in a Thymeleaf template. In addition, I also want this configuration page to be accessible through the Eureka Server at a different path, i.e. {eureka_url}:8761/config.

I have the template working, but when I start the Eureka Server, where the config template is also running, and want to access the Eureka dashboard through {eureka_url}:8761/, the Eureka Server gives me the following error:

```
Error resolving template "eureka/status", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

It seems to me that the Thymeleaf dependency in the class path, in combination with the Spring Eureka dependency, the template for the Eureka dashboard is being overwritten / not loaded.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? If so, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Eureka uses Freemarker as its template engine. It seems that somehow this conflicts with Thymeleaf.

After performing a lot of debugging, I found a workaround. Add this to your `application.properties`:

```
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=classpath:/templates/
spring.freemarker.prefer-file-system-access=false
```

For further discussion I opened a [bug report](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3290).

Comment: Gotta love these Java R/A conflicts ;). Your workaround worked. Thanks!